# Drop down menu to select a .css file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I did a little digging and I couldn't really find a good conversion for this because I'm a little slow and just starting out. I want to make it so my site will change to another CSS file when it's selected in a drop down menu. Currently, I know the code from this site which I'm following pretty closely, so it's pretty accurate to what I have right now: http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml

I want to do the same thing this would achieve, just in the form of a drop down menu instead of buttons. Any help? I've been messing with it for a while and digging for a reference and I can't really find one. Sorry if this is a bit of a silly question or if it's already been answered -- I just couldn't find anything!!

Comment: did you try: <form><ul> . <li><input></li> . <li><input></li>, etc.. ?

Comment: Yeah, all it seems to do is make the buttons vertical. I was thinking more along the lines of a select drop down? If that's possible. It's the look I'm aiming for. I've seen it done other places but I just can't figure out how.

Comment: you must add JS to the form to make it a dropdown menu, its not automatic. You could use bootstrap, it provides css + js for dropdowns and its really easy to use.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't actually install anything, everything needs to be by scratch, so I'm asking for that code too. If I can't get it it's fine, I'll just find a way to incorporate the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe?
I don't know if this works for what you want but you could try

```
<form name="myform">
    <div align="center">
        <select name="themePicker">
            <option onclick="switch_style('red');return false;" name="theme" value="red">Red</option>
            <option onclick="switch_style('green');return false;" name="theme" value="green">Green</option>            
            <option onclick="switch_style('blue');return false;" name="theme" value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This worked just as it needed to, thank you so much!!

Comment: Just pointing out that these all say `switch_style('blue')` here